# Invalid regular expression in R using grep() with lookarounds

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to construct `regular expression` dynamically in order to perform an exact match in `R` using `grep()`. This is the code I have:

```
names = c('John Doe', 'John-Doe', 'Doe John', 'Doe-John', 'John', 'Doe')

for(name in names) {
    pattern = paste('(?<![A-z]-)^\\b', name, '\\b$(?!-[A-z])', sep = '')
    index = grep(pattern, names)

    print(index)
}
```

Desired output:

- each name must be match exactly to an element within the `names` vector
- e.g., `John` should return only `index` `5` and nothing else

I tested my `regular expression` here https://regex101.com/r/uJhJwS/2 and it appears to work fine. However, I get the following error in `R`:

```
Error in grep(pattern, names) : 
  invalid regular expression '(?<![A-z]-)John Do$(?!-[A-z])', reason 'Invalid regexp'
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Your regex does not work as you think it does, it is equal to [`^John$`](https://regex101.com/r/uJhJwS/3), and that is what you are looking for: an exact match.

Comment: You can do this using `sapply` to examine each element of `names` and `which` to look for exact matches, without regex: `sapply(names, function(x) which(names == x))`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was using `\bJohn\b` prior to this and it didn't work. That's the only reason why I tried the `lookarounds`. But the `^$` helped me solve it. However, why did you say that the `regex` is equal to ^John$? Thanks.

Comment: @F.Gran The pattern in the regex101 fiddle is `(?<![A-z]-)^\bJohn\b$(?!-[A-z])`. The `(?<![A-z]-)` is a negative lookbehind that is executed at the start of the string (as it is right before `^`) and will always be true (i.e. it will always match) since there is no `[A-z]-` pattern before the start of the string. Similarly, there is no character after the end of the string, and thus `$(?!-[A-z])` is equal to `$` (the `(?!-[A-z])` will always return *true*). Also, note that [`[A-z]` matches more than ASCII letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901).